# What is the correct way to pause AsyncTask from the UI-thread

Tags: android

my AsyncTask should wait till event in the UI-thread happen.

so, I started to have simple while loop. However, in some of the devices that caused the UI thread to freeze. so after reading the following answer: 
[Fatal Spin-On-Suspend/Stuck on ThreadID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434182/fatal-spin-on-suspend-stuck-on-threadid)
[However, it is not quite the same - i put the while in the async-task not in main-activity]

I added Thread.sleep - and it seem to indeed solve the problem.

However, I feel like I'm doing something wrong here...I wonder what is the right way to do it.

Comment: why you don't use `object.wait()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not ever sleep or block the UI thread. Wait in the background thread of the AsyncTask.

One way is as suitianshi is pointing out with wait()/notifyAll(). Another one is to use a CountDownLatch:

1. In the UI thread create a latch: `CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);`
2. Subclass `AsyncTask` so that it takes a latch in the constructor and save it to a reference `mLatch`
3. in `doInBackground()`, when you need to wait call `mLatch.await()`. This will block the `AsyncTask`
4. in the UI, when the event you're waiting happens, call `latch.countDown()`

You should be good to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is going to be different...

```
my AsyncTask should wait till event in the UI-thread happen.
```

AsyncTask's are great for long running operations like http downloads, long i/o operations, image resizing, or any cpu intensive operation that would freeze the UI thread.

However, Android runs AsyncTasks sequentially and not in a pool by default.  [More details here](http://www.jayway.com/2012/11/28/is-androids-asynctask-executing-tasks-serially-or-concurrently/).

So if you have an AsyncTask that runs indefinitely, such as waiting for a UI action, you could likely block other AsyncTasks from running.  Leading to more deadlock and threading problems.

I would suggest any of the following:

1. Use a different [Executor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) for your AsyncTask so it runs similarly as it does today, but not to conflict with other AsyncTask items. This is the easiest approach.
2. Split your AsyncTask up into multiple tasks. The first one does whatever your current AsyncTask does up until the wait.  The second one does whatever your current one does after the UI event. The latter task gets queued by the UI that generated the event.
3. Use a dedicated Thread. Use the [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) class to marshall events back from the thread to the UI thread as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask is introduced for running things which takes long time. In earlier android OS, it can be done in main thread or UI thread. But now android forces us to do long running things in AsyncTask to make UI thread responsive. If you want during AsyncTask your android UI do nothing then you can simply add progress Dialog during it. Start progress Dialog in `onPreExecute()` & end it in `onPostExecute(String[] result)`.

Sample code : in AsyncTask

```
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait...");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.show();
    }
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
        // do something with result
    }
```

Thanks