# HTC One mini crashes XML parser

Tags: android, xml, android-asynctask

Device: HTC One mini

OS version: 4.3

Problem: AsyncTask XML reader crashes without triggering UncaughtExceptionHandler

.

I made a simple AsyncTask XML reader / parser that runs on most devices (OS 2.2 and older), but not on my HTC One mini (OS 4.3). When I try to run the AsyncTask, it always crashes at some point in code of doInBackground. Sometimes its on url.openConnection(), sometimes at httpurlconection.getInputStream(), sometimes at if(stream!=null)stream.close();, sometimes at some other random point in code. On very rare occasions the AsyncTask can finish itself, but crashes on the next request anyway.

The main loop is just waiting for the AsyncTask process to stop, by running a volatile boolean in while(XMLreaderAsyncTask.parsingnotComplete);

The kicker is that I use a DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler to write a TXT file report on all crashes, but it doesn’t work/trigger for this type of crash. It works fine if I trigger it by going out of bounds of an array, but not for what is causing the crash of the AsyncTask XML reader.

```
public static Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler androidDefaultUEH;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
...

androidDefaultUEH = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler()
{
    Write a TXT report file
androidDefaultUEH.uncaughtException(paramThread, paramThrowable);
}
...
}
```

I cant get eclipse to detect the phone as plugged in, so I cant get the LogCat report. At best, I put up checkpoint flags by writing into SharedPreferences

**EDIT 1:**
Calling XML AsyncTask

```
HandleXMLbackground XMLURL2=new HandleXMLbackground(contextvar,"http:/www.demowebsite.com/pageurloutput.xml");
XMLURL2.execute();
while(XMLURL2.parsingnotComplete);
String x=XMLURL2.xml_unparsed;
```

Code of AsyncTask

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Xml;

public class HandleXMLbackground extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
{
    public volatile boolean parsingnotComplete = true;
    private String urlString = "";
    static Context contxtxml;

    public String xml_unparsed="";

    public HandleXMLbackground(Context c,String url)
    {
        contxtxml=c;
        urlString=url;
    }


    public void parse(InputStream in)
    {
        LogLastAction5("parse start "+urlString);

            try
            {
                    XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
                    parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
                    parser.setInput(in, null);
                    parser.nextTag();

                    //Parsing happens here

            }
            catch (XmlPullParserException e)
            {
                LogLastAction5("xml F1 "+urlString+" "+e.getMessage()+" "+e.toString());
        }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                LogLastAction5("xml F2 "+urlString+" "+e.getMessage()+" "+e.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls)
    {
        parsingnotComplete = true;
        LogLastAction5("start "+urlString);

        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection universalconn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            universalconn.setConnectTimeout(7000);//ms
            universalconn.setReadTimeout(8000);//ms
            universalconn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            universalconn.setDoInput(true);
            universalconn.connect();
            InputStream stream2 = universalconn.getInputStream();
            parse(stream2);
            if(stream2!=null)stream2.close();
            universalconn.disconnect();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            LogLastAction5("fail 1 "+urlString+" "+e.getMessage()+" "+e.toString());
        }

        parsingnotComplete = false;
        return null;
    }

    protected static void LogLastAction5(String tx)
    {
         SharedPreferences settings1 = contxtxml.getSharedPreferences("com.myapp.stuff", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
         SharedPreferences.Editor seditor = settings1.edit();
         seditor.putString("LastAct5","xml "+tx);
         seditor.apply();
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**
I tried making the class into private class of Activity and added the onPostExecute. Still crashed on HTC One mini 9 times out of 9 on these commands:

```
1 universalconn.setRequestMethod("GET");
2 universalconn.connect();
3 stream2 = universalconn.getInputStream();
4 universalconn.setConnectTimeout(7000);//ms
5 stream2 = universalconn.getInputStream();
6 stream2 = universalconn.getInputStream();
7 universalconn.setConnectTimeout(7000);//ms
8 universalconn.setDoInput(true);
9 universalconn.setDoInput(true);
```

**EDIT 4:**
Found how to make phone go into developer mode, so now Eclipse shows logcat reports.
The overall report is a too long to post, but it ends in 2 red lines.
Will this help?

```
03-03 16:14:06.723: E/dalvikvm(20345): threadid=13: stuck on threadid=1, giving up
03-03 16:14:06.723: A/libc(20345): Fatal signal 16 (SIGSTKFLT) at 0x00004f79 (code=-6), thread 20345 (evelads.navimon)
```

I also had "threadid=13" be "threadid=11"

**EDIT 5:** Tested the code on different devices
Models the code works fine:

```
Samsung Galaxy y gt-s5360 (Android OS 2.3.6)
Samsung GT-N8000 (Android OS 4.1.2)
Samsung GT-I5500 (Android OS 2.3.7)
HTC One V (Android OS 4.0.3)
```

Models the code crashes 99.999% of the time:

```
HTC One Mini (Android OS 4.2)
Cube Talk 7X U51GT-C4 (Android OS 4.2.2)
```

Comment: Of course you should show the asynctask code and the polling code.

Comment: `The main loop is just waiting for the AsyncTask process to stop`. Why? Why is it interested? You should handle the result of the task in onPostExecute.

Comment: So you have tried this on other devices and no problems?

Comment: onPostExecute is not an option, as I do a hundred different XML requests with long differing action carried out after this. So I wait for the parsing to finish.

Comment: Yes, this crash only happens on HTC One mini. Other devices run this code just fine

Comment: Try following: Make your task a private class of your Activity. Move variables `parsingnotComplete` and `xml_unparsed` to your activity.

Comment: `while(XMLURL2.parsingnotComplete); //crashes here 98% of the time`. And what is the error message?

Comment: `parsingnotComplete = false;`. That should be done in onPostExecute. Please try first. Where do you set `xml_unparsed`?

Comment: My mistake. I removed the poor comment. The app doesn’t crash from `while(XMLURL2.parsingnotComplete);` It crashes when the main loop is on that action. The app really crashes in the `doInBackground()` method within the `try` part

Comment: `xml_unparsed` was supposed to be set in `//Parsing happens here` but the app crashes before it gets to that part, so it just returns `""`

Comment: I tried making the class into private class of Activity and added the onPostExecute. Still crashed on HTC One mini 9 times out of 9 on these commands:

`1 universalconn.setRequestMethod("GET");
2 universalconn.connect();
3 stream2 = universalconn.getInputStream();
4 universalconn.setConnectTimeout(7000);//ms
5 stream2 = universalconn.getInputStream();
6 stream2 = universalconn.getInputStream();
7 universalconn.setConnectTimeout(7000);//ms
8 universalconn.setDoInput(true);
9 universalconn.setDoInput(true);`

Comment: If you have no logcat its difficult to say something... Find drivers. You tried Samsung Kies or MoboRobo? `I tried making the class into private class`. The most important part orf that was moving the two variables.

Comment: Added device models on which the XML code works, and on which it doesn't. Looks like the newer and cheaper devices just don't like this thread overloading approach at all.

Comment: You should post much more of the logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking more into the issue I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434182/fatal-spin-on-suspend-stuck-on-threadid).  Evidently some phone models don't like the continuous uninterrupted loops and consider them an extraordinary crash scenario.

So my problem was in this:

```
while(XMLURL2.parsingnotComplete);
```

I changed it to this, and now don't get the crashing.

```
while(XMLURL2.parsingnotComplete)
{
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e){}
}
```